# Android generated R Class - syntax Error

Tags: android, syntax-error, generated-code

I have a project and its generated R class, generate its first string id in a strange form, **"=" and the resource name are switched!**

```
public static final class string {
    public static final int  = setting_ringtone1 0x7f06000e;
    public static final int about_disclaimer = 0x7f060015;
            .....
```

I tried already to change the name, but it doesn't works either!

Is someone facing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time I was writing the question I founded a soution! So I answering my own question.

In your **string.xml please don't use a space char** like

`<string name=" setting_notification"> ...`

instead of

`<string name="setting_notification"> ...`

The xml parser will prompt any error messages and your R will be generated with the sintax error!

Im my case I didn't see soon the problem, becuse all my strings are automatically generated from a URL, where all my strings are.